# Inner joins in sub queries

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can someone please explain the difference between the following queries. The joins in the sub queries look the same but the first runs okay and the second does not. In the second query the sub query does not seem to have access to the alias table e.

QUERY1

```
select    e.ename
          ,e.deptno
          ,(
                select count(*)
                from emp d
                where e.deptno = d.deptno
          ) dept_cnt
from      emp e
order by 2;
```

QUERY 2

```
select    e.ename
          ,e.deptno
          ,(
                select count(*)
                from emp    d
                inner join  e
                    ON      d.deptno = e.deptno
           ) dept_cnt
from      emp e
order by 2;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second query has bad syntax:

```
inner join  e
                    ON      d.deptno = e.deptno
```

Making an inner join with a table alias is not possible.

Comment: Isn't the sub query in query 1 an inner join with the table alias (e)?

Comment: No. In query 1 your are making a restriction on table emp (inner) through the where clause. The restriction uses table emp (outer) to select the required information.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. It clears up a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

query 2 is invalid sql. 
keywords `from` and `join` must be followd by a tablename and optional alias.

possible fix for query 2 (but query 1 is much better)

```
select  e.ename
       ,e.deptno
       ,(
           select count(*)
           from emp    d
           inner join emp e1
             ON  d.deptno = e1.deptno
             AND e1.deptno = e.deptno
        ) dept_cnt
from    emp e 
order by 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub queries can only use scalar values from higher leveled tables, these tables, themselves, are not into scope -- you can think of sub queries as loops that execute for each row of the higher level table(s).